# How to implement Angular Material 2 Autocomplete with AJAX

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am using Angular Material 2 Autocomplete in my Angular 4 project. How can I implement such that the autocomplete values are loading from an HTTP call, in this [example](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview#setting-separate-control-and-display-values)?

Can anyone give me a Plunker demo? Thank you

Answer (score 6):

*First of all, you should please show some attempt to solve your issue, but luckily I'm bored and will provide an answer ;)*

Here in this sample I'm using: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

we store that JSON result as an observable in `users`. Then we have our observable `filteredUsers` which will be shown in template. Since this is a http-request, we would want to use `distinctUntilChanged` and `debounceTime` of your choosing, to restrict the http-requests. The formcontrol we are using to capture the value user is typing is in this example `searchCtrl`. When listening to `valueChanges`, we use `switchMap` to flatten the result.

So based on the above comments, your code would look like the following:

**UPDATE (rxjs 6)**

```ts
this.filteredUsers = this.searchCtrl.valueChanges.pipe(
  startWith(null),
  debounceTime(200),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  switchMap(val => {
    return this.filter(val || '')
  })
 )
}

filter(val: string) {
  return this.users.pipe(
    map(response => response.filter(option => {
      return option.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) === 0
    }))
  )
}
```

and for the template, we use the `async` pipe:

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="searchCtrl">
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let user of filteredUsers | async" 
      [value]="user.name">
      <span>{{ user.name }}</span>
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cwyztb?file=app/autocomplete-simple-example.ts)**

---

**OLD:**

```ts
this.filteredUsers = this.searchCtrl.valueChanges
  .startWith(null)
  .debounceTime(200)
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .switchMap(val => {
    return this.filter(val || '')
})      

filter(val: string) {
  return this.users
    .map(response => response.filter(option => { 
      return option.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) === 0
    }));
}
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5dqmsw?file=app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: I seem to get an error on mine, I get response.filter is not a function even though I get data back from the server

Comment: brilliant!, thanks for the fiddle. Had to add this - `import 'rxjs/Rx'; `.